# is there a way to add a textarea to function with a floating label in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a simple for with 3 fields using vue.js, I am setting up "floating labels" on focus, as of now I have the inputs working nicely adding and removing class "active" as expected. When I try to add "textarea" my app is breaking and returning "cannot read value of null", is there a way to add the textarea as the inputs are setup?

html:

```
   <form @submit.prevent="submitForm()">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="floatWrapper" class="float-wrapper">
                    <label for="floatField">Enter Your Name</label>
                    <input
                      id="floatField"
                      v-model="contact_name"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control form-control--email"
                      @input="$v.contact_name.$touch"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <p v-if="$v.contact_name.$dirty">
                    <span v-if="!$v.contact_name.required" class="form__alert">
                      Please enter your name.
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  <div id="floatWrapper" class="float-wrapper">
                    <label for="floatField">Enter Your Email</label>
                    <input
                      v-model="contact_email"
                      type="email"
                      class="form-control form-control--email"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <p v-if="$v.contact_email.$dirty">
                    <span v-if="!$v.contact_email.required" class="form__alert">
                      Email is required.
                    </span>
                    <span v-if="!$v.contact_email.email" class="form__alert">
                      Please enter a valid email
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  <div id="floatWrapper" class="float-wrapper">
                    <label for="floatField">Enter Your Message</label>
                    <textarea
                      v-model="contact_message"
                      class="form-control form-control--textarea"
                      rows="5"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <p v-if="$v.contact_message.$dirty">
                    <span
                      v-if="!$v.contact_message.required"
                      class="form__alert"
                    >
                      Message must be over 10 characters
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  data-cursor="hover"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                >
                  Send Message
                  <font-awesome-icon far icon="arrow-right" />
                </button>
              </form>
```

js:

```
 mounted() {
    const labelFloating = (() => {
      
      const isFocus = (e) => {
        const target = e.target
        target.parentNode.classList.add('active')
      }

      const isBlur = (e) => {
        const target = e.target
        if (!target.value) {
          target.parentNode.classList.remove('active')
        }
      }

      
      const bindEvents = (element) => {
        const field = element.querySelector('input')
        field.addEventListener('focus', isFocus)
        field.addEventListener('blur', isBlur)

        const text = element.querySelector('textarea')
        text.addEventListener('focus', isFocus)
        text.addEventListener('blur', isBlur)
      }

      const initialize = () => {
        const floatWraps = document.querySelectorAll('.float-wrapper')

        floatWraps.forEach((element) => {
          if (element.querySelector('input').value) {
            element.classList.add('active')
          }   if (element.querySelector('textarea').value) {
            element.classList.add('active')
          } 

          bindEvents(element)
        })
      }

      return {
        init,
      }
    })()

    labelFloating.init()
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if (element.querySelector('input').value) {` will throw that error because you're chaining `.value` off the selector, but it doesn't exist and returns null. try this instead:

```
const selector = element.querySelector('input') || element.querySelector('textarea')

if (selector && selector.value) {
  element.classList.add('active')

  bindEvents(element)
}
```

And use the same refactor for the `bindEvents` method:

```
const bindEvents = (element) => {
  const field = element.querySelector('input') || element.querySelector('textrea')

  field.addEventListener('focus', isFocus)
  field.addEventListener('blur', isBlur)
}
```